# Adding border to JPanel impacts the layout of the components added to the panel

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am having a JPanel that is added to a JFrame. The panel have many buttons added vertically. when i set border to the panel, the size of buttons are getting smaller and layout is going off.

Can anyone advise why the layout is impacted because of the border setting?

Before adding border
[image: Image before border]

After adding border
[image]

Following is the code for the above design

```
frame = new JFrame();
    //frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setExtendedState(frame.getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    JPanel actionPanel = new JPanel();
    actionPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 450));
    actionPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(actionPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    actionPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1, 0, 0));

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GRAY));
    //panel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    actionPanel.add(panel);
    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    //GridbagLayout constraints
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.weighty = 0;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;

    JButton btnPos = new JButton("Point of Sale");
    Dimension btnPosDimension = new Dimension(actionPanel.getPreferredSize().width, 40);
    btnPos.setPreferredSize(btnPosDimension);
    panel.add(btnPos, gbc);

    gbc.gridy++;        
    JButton btnCategory = new JButton("Category");
    btnCategory.setPreferredSize(btnPosDimension);
    panel.add(btnCategory, gbc);

    gbc.gridy++;        
    JButton btnProduct = new JButton("Product");
    btnProduct.setPreferredSize(btnPosDimension);
    panel.add(btnProduct, gbc);

    gbc.gridy++;        
    JButton btnVendor = new JButton("Vendor");
    btnVendor.setPreferredSize(btnPosDimension);
    panel.add(btnVendor, gbc);

    gbc.weighty = 1;
    gbc.gridy++;
    panel.add(Box.createGlue(), gbc); //Adding a component to feel the area.

    JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
    actionPanel.add(panel_1);


    JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
    frame.getContentPane().add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: So, basically you're asking why code that you've not shown is not working. No, I have no idea. If you don't get good advice from someone else, please do create a [mcve] that replicates the problem for us.

Comment: It looks like you have specified the size of the container that holds your JPanel. Thus if you put a border on the JPanel, there is less space available for the items inside the panel.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, Added the code.

Comment: @FredK, Yes i have specified the size of the Panel, how does that affects the components inside when adding border? Can you please explain me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borders are added to the inside of a JPanel so there is less space available inside. You have specified the size of the container that holds your panel, so when the border is added there isn't enough space for the contents.

Comment: @Jane Parker, Thanks, That was the issue. i have reduced the button size by 2 and now its working fine

Answer (score 1):

I just reduced the buttons' width 2. because that 2 using by line border.

This is the working code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        //frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setExtendedState(frame.getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JPanel actionPanel = new JPanel();
        actionPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 450));
        actionPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(actionPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        actionPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1, 0, 0));

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GRAY));
        //panel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        actionPanel.add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        //GridbagLayout constraints
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.weighty = 0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;

        JButton btnPos = new JButton("Point of Sale");
        Dimension btnPosDimension = new Dimension(actionPanel.getPreferredSize().width - 2, 40);
        btnPos.setPreferredSize(btnPosDimension);
        panel.add(btnPos, gbc);

        gbc.gridy++;        
        JButton btnCategory = new JButton("Category");
        btnCategory.setPreferredSize(btnPosDimension);
        panel.add(btnCategory, gbc);

        gbc.gridy++;        
        JButton btnProduct = new JButton("Product");
        btnProduct.setPreferredSize(btnPosDimension);
        panel.add(btnProduct, gbc);

        gbc.gridy++;        
        JButton btnVendor = new JButton("Vendor");
        btnVendor.setPreferredSize(btnPosDimension);
        panel.add(btnVendor, gbc);

        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.gridy++;
        panel.add(Box.createGlue(), gbc); //Adding a component to feel the area.

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        actionPanel.add(panel_1);


        JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


}
```